# Function output is only showing as a value of 16

Tags: c

When I run this and input 2 values, it always only ever outputs the value of 16. I never receive anything else. Please can someone show me where I've gone wrong with this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define result

int higher(int num1 , int num2);

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int val1;
    int val2;
    int num;

    num = higher(val1, val2);

    printf("Enter two numbers: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &val1, &val2);
    printf("The higher number is: %d\n", num);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int higher(int num1 , int num2) {
    // Based on what values are called from the function
    // num1 or num2 should reflect as the highest.
    int result;

    if (num1 <= num2)
        result = num2;
    else
        result = num1;

    return result;
}
```

Comment: You are calling the function before you've assigned values to its arguments.

Comment: Thanks, so should I move that before int main()?

Comment: No. You must move it under `scanf` line.

Comment: Note that the body of `higher` can just be: `return num1 <= num2 ? num2 : num1;`

Comment: 1) get the values *FIRST* (`scanf`), *THEN* compare (`higher()`).  2) *ALWAYS* check the return value of scanf().  If "scanf()" doesn't == 2, you know somebody mis-typed a digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the function before getting the values in `scanf` it should be like this.

```
printf("Enter two numbers: ");
scanf("%d %d", &val1, &val2);
num = higher(val1, val2);
printf("The higher number is: %d\n", num);
```

Comment: NOTE: you should *ALWAYS* check scanf()'s return value: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/return-values-of-printf-and-scanf-in-c-cpp/